# How can i save and retrieve a generic relation to a model field in django-rest-framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-contenttypes

I have 2 models Photo and Wedding which both have a generic relation to 2 models comments and likes:

Here are the like and comments models:

```
class Like(models.Model):
     user=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="likes")
     content_type=models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
     object_id=models.PositiveIntegerField()
     content_object=generic.GenericForeignKey(content_type,object_id)

     class Meta:
         unique_together=(("user","content_type","object_id"))

class Comments(models.Model):
     user=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="comments")
     text=models.TextField(max_length=2000)
     content_type=models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
     object_id=models.PositiveIntegerField()
     content_object=generic.GenericForeignKey(content_type,object_id)
```

How can I save the comments to a specific photo or wedding using django-rest-framework for example /photos/1/ or /weddings/1/ ? Also how can I retrieve the comments in my wedding detail or my photo detail to show the comments of a photo or wedding, for example 127.0.0.1:8000/photos/1/ or 127.0.0.1:8000/weddings/1/? I have looked at the documentation but it does not make sense to me.